# Internet on Ubuntu server connected to modem is not working

Tags: networking, internet, router, modem

I'm experimenting to connect my desktop machine running Ubuntu server to the modem.

There are two eth outputs. One goes to the router and I used the other one for my desktop computer.

The Internet is not working when connected this way. It works if I connect it to the router eth output.

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to connect my machine to the modem? I'd like to move the router on another room but keep the modem around my computer connected via a short Ethernet cable.

How to fix this?

The fact that I'm running Ubuntu server could be potentially irrelevant. The machine uses openbox as window manager.

My setup looks like this:

[image: modem to PC and separate router]

Comment: I have tried this. Find the `eth0` and make a copy for `eth1`. That should fix it. It is commonly found in the routing tables... I have done it with success but don't remember now.

Comment: How to copy eth0 into 1?

Comment: Searching for it... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you topology is

```
    --------    ---------- eth1        ---------
    |  PC  |    | server |-------------| modem |
    --------    ----------        eth0 ---------
    eth0|           |eth0
        |-----------|
```

Solution is something like this

EXP:

PC setup

```
eth0

ip: 192.168.2.100
nm: 255.255.255.0
gw: 192.168.2.1
```

Server setup

```
eth0

ip: 192.168.2.1
nm: 255.255.255.0

eth1

ip: 192.168.1.100
nm: 255.255.255.0
gw: 192.168.1.1
```

Modem lan setup

```
ip: 192.168.1.1
nm: 255.255.255.0
```

After this you need to do fallowing on server

Enable IP forwarding. This is done either by using

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Then, we will add a rule telling to forward the traffic

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

and finally, we ask IPtables to masquerade

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Edit 1

In this case problem can occur on router setup

EXP 2

Modem setup

```
wan: ip from provider
lan ip: 192.168.1.1 
lan nm: 255.255.255.0

# you can setup dhcp or you can setup PC(Ubuntu server)

ip: 192.168.1.100
nm: 255.255.255.0
gw: 192.168.1.1

dns: 8.8.8.8 # or from your ISP
```

Router setup

```
wan ip: 192.168.1.99
wan nm: 255.255.255.0
wan gw: 192.168.1.1

lan ip: 192.168.2.1
lan nm: 255.255.255.0

# you can configure dhcp for router clients
```

PC!, PC2, laptop setup

```
ip: 192.168.2.xxx
nm: 255.255.255.0
gw: 192.168.2.1

or via dhcp from router
```

I only can see that you have problem to connecting server to modem.
Put the output from command `sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces`
Or you can change in `/etc/network/interfaces` from

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
```

to

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Save, restart network and ...

Comment: I updated my question to be clearer. There is no server but a normal computer running Ubuntu server and openbox.

Comment: Actually is this setup supported at all? My brother says it's impossible to have a router and a pc connected to one modem.

Comment: this still seems a bit confusing. Clarify, does the modem actually have enough lan ports? Which IP addresses are you using in the linux machine you are trying to connect to the modem? what are the networks and netmask of the already existing in Router and Modem.

Comment: @JoãoSilva I'm not that good in networking, but the modem receives the cable from the street and has ETH outputs: ETH1 and ETH2 (that's how they are labeled). ETH1 goes to the router. What it's unclear to me is if it's possible to connect my PC to ETH2 from the modem, not from the router. So: both PC and the router would be directly connected to the modem via eth cables. Is that possible? The ip address is probably dynamic when connected to the router. Without doing any changes, by connecting it to the modem, the PC doesn't get an ip address.